# Duplicate rows finding the mysql query

Tags: mysql, duplicates, rows, duplicate-data

[image: Table name "Attandance"].
Please Help me the query how to find duplicate rows..

Answer (score 1):

You mean Duplication of abs field ?

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> GROUP BY abs HAVING COUNT(abs) > 1
```